# jQuery(v1.4.2 ) $post not working in rails 1.9.2?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, post

environment : jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.2
Rails : 1.9.2
Browser : firefox , chrome , IE8

jquery post not working with rails 1.9.2

```
$.post("/selectsite/createsitename", {
                      sitename: name
                     }, function(data){
});
```

my code was working rails 1.8.7 with jquery 1.4.2 .
Now i am upgrading to rails 1.9.2 with jquery 1.4.2 but not working the above post method .
any one have solution for this issue?

Comment: Firstly its not rails 1.9.2 but ruby 1.9.2 . Are you using rails 3.1? If so, jquery is already included by default and if you try to include it again somewhere else in your code, it shall not work .

Comment: Sorry , it's ruby 1.9.2. my code is working upto jquery post method . it's redirecting to my home page

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean ruby 1.9.2, not rails 1.9.2 ;)
Do you see any error in browser's javascript console or in Rails logs?
Please provide more details.

Comment: Please include such 'answers' as a comment. You shouldn't post an answer asking for more information.